# Missing Menu Bar in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, menubar

When I opened up Visual Studio 2010 this morning, my Menu Bar (you know, the bar with File, Edit, etc. on it) was missing.  I've tried all of the right-click menus, customize options, Function keys and Google searches that I can think of but to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like registry damage, HKCU\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\10.0_Config perhaps.  Try running devenv.exe with the /ResetSettings command line option first.  Next is rerunning setup.exe and choosing the Repair option.

Comment: devenv.exe /ResetSettings fixed it! Thank you!