# The menu bar of Visual Studio 2010 doesn't display

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I upgraded from VS 2008 to VS 2010 but the menu bar has not displayed. That only displays when I press the "Alt" key. I refered the question in following link: [Missing Menu Bar in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905436/missing-menu-bar-in-visual-studio-2010) and performed as follows the instructions but no success.

Does anybody give me some instructions?

Comment: Hi josh K, I don't understand what do you want to speak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VS 2010 RTM out of the box does not have a feature to hide the main menu.  There is an [extension that hides the menu bar](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/bdbcffca-32a6-4034-8e89-c31b86ad4813); did you install that?  If so, uninstalling it from the extension manager will restore the default behavior.